# why laravel 9 bootstrap auth doesn't have a style when running on mobile phone but working correctly on localhost?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, styling

I am working with laravel 9 project with auth package (bootstrap) and the newely added "vite" where I need to run "**npm run dev**" for the app to work. and it works correctly on localhost.

when I open the app from a mobile on the same network, it works without a style, like if we installed the auth but without importing bootstrap !

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost or 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address for that one server, computer, or device. It will not be shared even if it's on the same network since it's the loopback address for the server, computer, or device it's called on. Since Vite's development server starts a **local** server, it'll only be available on that device.

To share it on the network you have to either set the [server host](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-host) in the config to your network IP, it should be something along the lines of `192.168.X.XXX`.

```javascript
export default defineConfig({
    ...
    server: {
        host: '192.168.X.XXX'
    }
});
```

Or you can set the server host using the `--host` flag if you're using the Vite CLI or in your `package.json` file.

```diff
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host=192.168.X.XXX",
    "build": "vite build"
},
```

Or you can skip all that and build the assets before you share them on the network for testing on other devices, that's my preferred method at least.

```bash
npm run build
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. I tried the last solution "npm run build" and it worked .. I will try the above solutions as well .. THANKS .. and if you could provide further explanation about the build command, I'll be grateful, e.g: does it mean that it will install the files on my localhost root and it will be served with the laravel app ?

Comment: When the `@vite` directive is called, it will first look for a `hot` file in `/public`, that Vite creates. That file stores the address of its dev server. If that file is not found it will look for a `manifest.json` file in the build directory, which is in `/public/build` by default. You can see all of this in the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/71c7fe77b432966162a0ca2ec957c033ae591954/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Vite.php#L117) for the `@vite` directive. The built assets should be either committed and deployed. Or generated via CI/CD or manually on the server.

Comment: You can also read more about it in the [Running Vite](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#running-vite) section of Laravel's documentation. I do recommend reading the Bundling Assets (Vite) part of the documentation to familiarize yourself with how Laravel uses Vite to bundle assets.

Hope that help you out @php_man 